# How to split a string efficiently and calculate with its values?

Tags: c#, string, split, console

I have recently began to start learning C# and try to write a program that's similar to a calculator in a console. I've already done it with two integers and it worked. Now I am trying to write the code allowing more user inputs to calculate with.

The thing is, that I have stuck at spliting the string from the user-input. So let's say for example he writes:
`1 + 2 * 3 - 5` I want to split it where the space happens. It should still be splitting when the user uses **more than just one spaces** in between. It's like the same as `1,2,,3,,,,5,6,,,4` : *How can you split by the comma when there are MORE than one comma used?* I only want the integers (and the operators from example 1).

I have already tried with `[string_name].Split(' ')` and `[string_name].Split(',')` but it only seems to ignore ONE char variable between the user-input-values I am interested in. That makes it impossible for me to put the values in an array and convert them to int.

Last question regarding my first example (`1 + 2 * 3 - 5`):
Besides accepting multiple spaces/comma, *how can you split this string input efficiently, keeping int inputs and the operators?* My idea was to save every uneven input value (1, 2, 3, 5) and every even input value (+, *, -,/) in an array each. I considered to put the operators into a `switch` with 4 cases and convert the string_array with numbers to integers. After that I would have put them all together into the exact same order like the user-input using `for`.

The thing is: Assuming I implement it correctly, I think that the calculation would be solved from left to right without considering the precedence of '*' and '/'.

*Someone an idea how you can solve this problem with the "advanced" calculator efficiently?* I have thought for a long time and tried all I could, but it doesn't seem to work ... Makes me sad a bit. I'd really like to solve this problem somehow.

Comment: With `StringSplitOptions` you can specify to ignore empty entries. Take a look at `Split` documentation first.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/alexdandria/ExpressionEvaluator) maybe can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Well the answer to your first question, you can pass an overload to `Split` that will ignore empty entries:

```
str.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

So more traditionally, you'd want to parse the string entirely so you could handle things like parenthesis and the case where there is no space: `4*(1+2)` for instance.